# DateTools timeAgoSinceNow. How to limit the number of days?

Tags: ios, swift, date, datetime, swift3

I'm using `MatthewYork/DateTools` in my project to show date user friendly.

Using it with code:

```
date.timeAgoSinceNow
```

For example for 04.05.2017 it will show `Yesterday`.

For 03.05.2017 - `2 days ago`

For 02.05.2017 - `3 days ago`

For 27.04.2017 - `Weak ago` or something like this.

I can't find in the documentation **how to limit number of days, when `timeAgoSinceNow` will work**. I want it to work only for 3 last days for example.

Like:

For 04.05.2017 show `Yesterday`.

For 03.05.2017 - `2 days ago`

For 02.05.2017 - `3 days ago`

For 27.04.2017 - `27 april`.

Looking for standard solution from this framework.

Comment: Look at the logic for `- (NSString *)timeAgoSinceDate:(NSDate *)date format:(DateAgoFormat)format` from https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools/blob/master/DateTools/DateTools/NSDate%2BDateTools.m I guess that's where you code goes and device what to show.

Comment: Or `public func timeAgo(since date:Date, numericDates: Bool = false, numericTimes: Bool = false) -> String` https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools/blob/master/DateToolsSwift/DateTools/Date%2BTimeAgo.swift didn't check the Swift Tag.